# Is there a name for this method of data consolidation / reduction?

Tags: sequences-and-series, data-analysis

Say I have a data series of N elements.

I want to create second series that represents a rough approximation of the first series with a reduced set of elements M.

**Question 1:  Is there a proper name for the general set of techniques used to accomplish this?**

**Question 2:  Is there a specific name for the following technique or similar techniques?**

1 - Divide N / M, which produces a number of elements per bucket B.

2 - Calculate mean for first B elements. Calculate mean for second set of B elements.. so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word describing this process is called "**downsampling**".  Sometimes referred to as "**decimation**".

Having come from a 3D background, I am familiar with reduction of points in a 3D mesh as "decimation". The terms seem to be used similarly in fields of computer graphics, communications, and economic analysis.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downsampling_(signal_processing)